# I use Aspose to embed image OLE to Excel, but when I open it first time, it shows as a image, I have to check it twice to transfer it to an OLEObject

Tags: java, aspose

I have tried POI, spire, and Aspose. And it is all the same problem.

[image: First time I open it]

[image: When I open it a second time]

Comment: the picture is above

Comment: I think this is MS Excel's behavior where you have to double-click on the embedded ole object to open it from MS Excel. Anyways, could you share your current Excel file (containing the OLE Object), current code using Aspose.Cells and your expected file (you may create your desired Excel file with ole object manually in MS Excel)? We will check it soon.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.